# Generating disposable images for testing/debugging on OS X

Tags: macos, raster

When writing code that handles images, it's easy on Linux to generate sample raster images using `ppmmake`, `bggen`, and `pnmpaste`.

Are there any similar utilities available on OS X, using MacPorts, brew, ImageMagick, SVG, or a combination?

One solution (writing brief code that writes out ppm files, and then converting to png using ImageMagick's convert) is straightforward but gets tedious.

Comment: http://brewformulas.org/Netpbm

Comment: @robertklep Thanks.. I'm shivering at the thought of polluting my Terminal and my /usr/*/bin path with 300 utilities. I guess it's the option of last resort.

Comment: Just install ImageMagick under `homebrew` - it's simple.

Comment: @Calaf you can run `brew unlink netpbm` after installation and add `/usr/local/Cellar/netpbm/*/bin/` to your `$PATH` whenever you want to use them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. Who would have thought that "input-file" is optional when "SYNOPSIS: convert [input-option] input-file [output-option] output-file" appears at the start of "man convert" (without square brackets around "input-file")?

Comment: I think IM is more flexible than manpage syntax permits! What is it you actually want to generate?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Nothing terribly fancy. I'd simply like to debug HTML5 canvas drawing code with a checkerboard image or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ImageMagick examples:

```
# Checkerboard
convert -size 200x200 pattern:checkerboard checker.png
```

[image]

```
# Pure b/w checkerboard
convert -size 200x200 pattern:checkerboard -threshold 50% checker.png
```

[image]

```
# Plain gradient
convert -size 200x200 gradient:red-black grad.png
```

[image]

```
# Partially transparent gradient
convert -size 200x200 gradient:"rgba(255,255,0,0.3)-rgba(0,128,0,0.6)" grad.png
```

[image]

```
# French flag!
convert -size 50x100 xc:blue xc:white xc:red +append france.png
```

[image]

```
# French flag hanging on horizontal pole to stdout
convert -size 150x100 xc:blue xc:white xc:red -append -compress none png:

P3
150 300
4294967295
0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535 0 0 65535
```

[image]

Comment: Vive (aussi) la flexibilité!